# How can I access shared spreadsheet using Google Spreadsheet API?

Tags: google-sheets

I just did an example of Google Spreadsheet API on Android, and I can list and read all spreadsheets owned by me. However, I cannot see or access any spreadsheets other people shared with me. I wonder if anyone knows what I'm talking about and can help me?